# Extracting RAW Stereo Images from the Pixel 2 using RAW_PRIVATE Image Format

Tags: android

I am currently making use of the RAW_SENSOR image format from the google samples for [Camera2Raw](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Raw). I get a DNG File output which indeed, is the RAW output file (size about 23MB). But, I am more interested in the RAW_PRIVATE image format. This is because, as it mentions in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html#RAW_PRIVATE), this format is "a single channel image with **implementation dependent pixel layout**". I hope to use this to extract the stereo images the Pixel 2 creates with its Dual Pixel Auto Focus system as described in this [blog post](https://ai.googleblog.com/2017/10/portrait-mode-on-pixel-2-and-pixel-2-xl.html).